# The type org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMStAXWrapper is not visible

Tags: java, migration, apache-axis, axiom

I have below code in old version. Now I have upgraded the axis2 version from 1.1.1 to 1.6.2. It then have compile problem as indicated below. I find in the web with link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-4363 
But I do not understand it. First of all Do I need to amend code? If yes, is there any example for me to follow?

```
    if (reader.getEventType() == javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT && reader.getName().equals(new javax.xml.namespace.QName(org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMConstants.XOP_NAMESPACE_URI, org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMConstants.XOP_INCLUDE)))
    {
         java.lang.String id = org.apache.axiom.om.util.ElementHelper.getContentID(reader, "UTF-8");
         object.set_return(((org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.MTOMStAXSOAPModelBuilder)
 ((org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMStAXWrapper) 
reader).getBuilder()).getDataHandler(id));
    <--- highlight this The type org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMStAXWrapper is not visible


          reader.next();
          reader.next();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be generated code. If you upgrade from Axis2 1.1.1 to 1.6.2, then you need to regenerate that code. Note that the usual best practice applies here: generated code should always be generated during the build, not checked into the source control system.